# Magnitude of the Fourier coefficient of a boolean function

Tags: fourier-analysis, boolean

This is exercise 1.5 from Analysis of Boolean Functions by Ryan O'Donnell.

Suppose $f: \{-1, 1\}^n \to \{-1, 1\}$. We want to show that at most one Fourier coefficient has magnitude exceeding $1/2$.

Fourier coefficient is defined as $\hat{f}(S) = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{x \in \{-1, 1\}^n} f(x) (\prod_{i \in S} x_i)$.

I do not think Parseval's identity will help here since we can have a non-boolean $L^2$ norm $1$ function that has more than one Fourier coefficient exceeding $1/2$.

Any hint on this?
Thank you.

Comment: I think I have a proof. Assuming that heavy coefficient is at $\hat{f}(\emptyset)$, which we can do by multiplying with the appropriate character function $\chi_S(x) = \prod_{i \in S}(x_i)$, we can just count how many values $f(x) = 1$ and $f(x) = -1$. And we can argue that any character function hits $1$ and $-1$ the same number of times. So, the inner product cannot achieve a value bigger than $1/2$. But does anyone have a nicer proof?